# How to correctly fetch data from an API with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch some data from a local API but I am getting the following error:

[image]

The API is working fine as I tested here:

[image]

I am trying to fetch the data like this:

```
export class WhereWeFly extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
      fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/content/home")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => this.setState({markerProps: data}));
    }

    state = {
        markerProps: {},
        activeMarker: {},          
        selectedPlace: {},
        //Polyline variables
        clicked: false,
        index: 0,
        routes: []
    };
```

Code where the error happens:

```
       <Map
            google={this.props.google}
            zoom={zoom}
            style={mapStyles}
            initialCenter={initCenter}>
        
            {this.state.markerProps.Items.map(item =>
                <Marker
                    onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
                    name={item.id}
                    position={{lat: item.coordinates.lat, lng: item.coordinates.lng}}
                />)}
```

What am I missing here?
Thank you!

Comment: Your `state.markerProps` variable is not defined before you call `componentDidMount` thus the error. You should initialize your `state` with default values in your constructor.

Comment: Have you tried logging `this.state.markerProps` in render? What does it show? (Also: You have two downvotes and two comments.)

Comment: I did not downvote and this is out of my technical expertise, but at a guess the reasons for downvotes might be one or more of "pictures of text", "patchy MRE" ([mre]), "no demonstrated research effort", "authour did not take the [tour]"...

Comment: @zhulien Thank you. So I placed the state now before the componentDidMount but it didn't work.

Comment: @idmean I did and doesn't show a thing

Comment: try to log your respone before setState like this: `.then((data) =>{ console.log(data);this.setState({markerProps: data})});`, and check what have you received.

Comment: @SaeedShamloo I get: Uncaught TypeError: this.state.markerProps.Items is undefined. It seems the application breaks before the console.log

Comment: In your initial state value add property `items` to `markerProps`, like this: `markerProps: { 
items: [] },`

Comment: @SaeedShamloo Oh great, now the console logs the data! But the application still breaks at that point

Comment: @SaeedShamloo TypeError: this.state.markerProps is undefined

Comment: did you edit this one? `.then((data) =>{ console.log(data);this.setState({markerProps: data})});` ? do you receive data successfully?

Comment: I did and got the data on the console. Items: (6) […], Count: 6, ScannedCount: 6 }
​
Count: 6
​

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240064/discussion-between-bob-and-saeed-shamloo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the problem by providing `Items` in the `marketProps`, when you want set the intial value of your state, like this:

```
state = {
    markerProps: { Items: [] },
    activeMarker: {},          
    selectedPlace: {},
    //Polyline variables
    clicked: false,
    index: 0,
    routes: []
};
```